# How can I implement JQuery Pagination into a custom script?

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, flickr

I am using a bespoke Jquery/PHP gallery script which pulls images from a Flickr feed.
I have tried to implement the JQuery pagination plugin, to no avail.

Here is the code...

```
<?php

require_once('php/simplepie.inc');

$feed = new Simplepie('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds /photos_public.gne?id=44262300@N06&lang=en-us&format=rss_200');

   $feed->handle_content_type();



function image_from_description($data) {

preg_match_all('/<img src="([^"]*)"([^>]*)>/i', $data, $matches);

return $matches[1][0];

}



function select_image($img, $size) {

$img = explode('/', $img);

$filename = array_pop($img);



$s = array(

    '_s.', // square

    '_t.', // thumb

    '_m.', // small

    '.',   // medium

    '_b.'  // large

  );



   $img[] = preg_replace('/(_(s|t|m|b))?\./i', $s[$size], $filename);

   return implode('/', $img);

}

?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("#images div").quickpaginate({ perpage: 4, showcounter: false, pager :  $("#image_counter") });
});

</script>




  <div class="album-wrapper" id="images">

        <?php foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item): ?>

            <div class="photo">

                <?php

                    if ($enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()) {



                        $img = image_from_description($item->get_description());

                        $full_url = select_image($img, 4);

                        $thumb_url = select_image($img, 0);

                        echo '<a href="' . $full_url . '" class="thickbox" title="' . $enclosure->get_title() . '"><img id="photo_' . $i . '" src="' . $thumb_url . '" /></a>'."\n";

                    }

                ?>


            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="image_counter"></div>
```

Can anyone see what I have missed or I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the execution of the code on the client to see where the quickpaginate function is failing?  I'm not familiar with the plugin, but a little more info on the actual error you are experiencing would be helpful for anyone trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried trying to isolate the area where the error might be located? Can you figure it out if it is in the PHP-side of your code or on the JavaScript side?

In any case, I've had success using the jQuery [pager](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html) companion plugin for the [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html) plugin. It doesn't work very well for very long lists of data, however.

Comment: I cant pin it down to whether it is PHP or Jquery thats causing the issue. Here is my code, can you see why the two aren't linking?